# How to execute system command in Erlang and get results using os:cmd/1?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

When I try to execute following command that returns error or doesn't exit on Windows - I always get empty list instead of error returned as string so for example:

I get:

```
[] = os:cmd("blah").
```

instead of something like

```
"command not found" = os:cmd("blah").
```

In linux - everything works as expected so I get "/bin/sh: line 1: blah: command not found\n"

Therefore I cannot rely on that function when I need to know how execution finished etc.
Please suggest some general way how to execute command and get results including error code.

Thanks!

Comment: this behavior can be observed only using werl.exe - not erl.exe

Comment: Could you show results of `os:get_env("COMSPEC")` and `erlang:system_info(os_type)` in erl.exe and werl.exe, please?

Comment: In both cases (erl/werl) I get same following results: 

1> os:getenv("COMSPEC").
"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
2> erlang:system_info(os_type).
{win32,nt}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not familiar with windows at all, but I'm sure, you should look  [this](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/os.erl#L188). This is implementation `os:cmd/1` function.

There is problem with `os:cmd/1`. This function doesn't let you know, was command execution successful or not, so you only have to rely on certain command shell behaviour (which is platform dependent).

I'd recommend you to use `erlang:open_port/2` function. Something like that:

```
my_exec(Command) ->
    Port = open_port({spawn, Command}, [stream, in, eof, hide, exit_status]),
    get_data(Port, []).

get_data(Port, Sofar) ->
    receive
    {Port, {data, Bytes}} ->
        get_data(Port, [Sofar|Bytes]);
    {Port, eof} ->
        Port ! {self(), close},
        receive
        {Port, closed} ->
            true
        end,
        receive
        {'EXIT',  Port,  _} ->
            ok
        after 1 ->              % force context switch
            ok
        end,
        ExitCode =
            receive
            {Port, {exit_status, Code}} ->
                Code
        end,
        {ExitCode, lists:flatten(Sofar)}
    end.
```

So function `my_exec/1` will return process *exit code* along with process stdout.

Comment: It may be that too much time has gone by or that enough has changed in the erlang world that the protocol has changed, but whenever I use this, I've never had the `{'EXIT', Port, _}` branch in the receive match. Whether the command exits 0, nonzero, or dies due to a signal, I've never observed a message matching that pattern. Is it necessary?

Comment: You don't need to handle the `EXIT` in this case because you're using the `eof` option.